# How to erase Core Graphics Context drawing in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have used core graphics in a view to drawing lines. Now, I need to erase the lines that I daw using an erase button. I don't know what should I do to get a clear view with no lines.

Here is the code I used for drawing lines.

```
struct Line {
    var points: [CGPoint]
    var strokeColor: UIColor
    var strokeWidth: CGFloat
}

class CanvasView: UIView {
    private var lines: [Line] = []
    private var strokeWidth: CGFloat = 8.0
    private var strokeColor: UIColor = .white
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        lines.forEach { line in
            context.setStrokeColor(line.strokeColor.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(line.strokeWidth)
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            
            for (index, point) in line.points.enumerated() {
                if index == 0 {
                    context.move(to: point)
                } else {
                    context.addLine(to: point)
                }
            }
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with: event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first.location(in: self) else { return }
        let newLine = Line(points: [point], strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidth: strokeWidth)
        lines.append(newLine)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with: event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first.location(in: self) else { return }
        guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else { return }
        
        lastLine.points.append(point)
        lines.append(lastLine)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

I have connected this CanvasView: UIView class to my own view to use Core Graphics Context drawing.

I need a way to erase what I draw in my UIView using a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drawing is depends on your list of `Line` so the thing you just need to do is make func where you clear all your lines then redraw. So at this time, when you call `draw(_ rect:)` again check if there is no value in your `lines` then clear view.

```swift
class CanvasView: UIView {
    private var lines: [Line] = []
    private var strokeWidth: CGFloat = 8.0
    private var strokeColor: UIColor = .white
    
    func clearView() {
        self.lines = []
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        if self.lines.count == 0 {
            // context clear here
            context.clear(self.bounds)
        }
        
        lines.forEach { line in
            context.setStrokeColor(line.strokeColor.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(line.strokeWidth)
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            
            for (index, point) in line.points.enumerated() {
                if index == 0 {
                    context.move(to: point)
                } else {
                    context.addLine(to: point)
                }
            }
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        let newLine = Line(points: [point], strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidth: strokeWidth)
        lines.append(newLine)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else { return }
        
        lastLine.points.append(point)
        lines.append(lastLine)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

And in your `ViewController` just simply call func `canvasView.clearView()`

Comment: Thank you, But it didn't work when I tried calling the function clearView() inside a button in my ViewController using an instance of my class. The lines are still there and I also tried lines.removeAll() Still, no luck.

Comment: Dear @DeltrinSam, have you check if it call to func ``clearView()`` and have you check if it was redraw in ``drawRect()``?

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out. I have added my custom-created CanvasView class to my view only on the storyboard. 

When I created an outlet for my view I inherited it from UIView. 

It worked when I changed it from the UIView to my custom-created CanvasView class. 

[ @IBOutlet weak var canvasView: CanvasView!   ]

Comment: Dear @DeltrinSam, no problem just marked the answer is accepted in order to closed this question ^^

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to inverse what I have painted using drawRect()?

Comment: Dear @DeltrinSam, it's another problem but I will give you a hint. Your painted is depends on your list of ``Line`` so if you want to inverse just remove the latest index in your list of ``Line`` and redraw again